# How to Integrate MWPhotoBrowser with my existing StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mwphotobrowser

MWPhotoBrowser is not using any xib files. My project is using StoryBoard.

So what I did was.
I used `[navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller:mwphotobrowser anomated:yes]`

To push to MWPhotoBrowser. Everything is working fine except.

When I tap on the back button in MWPhotoBrowser it takes me to the previous view (NavigationViewController buttons seems to load) but the background is black and I cannot see the contents of my previous ViewController.

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

I want it to behave like the regular storyboard navigation so that when i click on back it takes me to previous view and also show its content. Right now its showing the previous view as black screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved the problem.
Here is what i was doing wrong.

I was calling the MWPhotobrowser from viewdidload of another viewcontroller and because of that it was behaving strangly.

I called it from action of a button and now everything is working fine.

Solution to the problem -> Don't call it from ViewDidload